# How to execute firmware command from gcode

Tags: marlin, g-code, firmware

I wrote a command in Marlin firmware which changes Neopixel color based on extruder temperature.

In my start G-code for I set the color to white. How to execute my above command from the end G-code so that the the color changes per request?

Answer (score 1):

As your color is based on the temp reading, as far as I know, there is no G-code to read a temperature and push that value to another command.
The way you can do it is:

1. Static color change - use same method as you are setting to white
2. Intercept firmware temperature reading function and push that value to led module